# Word VBA: Watch List Disappears

Tags: vba, ms-word

This problem has been happening for awhile now, but with the particular piece of code I am now trying to debug, it has become really difficult for me to live with.

The issue is rather basic: every time I click F8 to step to the next line of code, the Expression, Value and Type columns in the watch window goes completely blank.  The Context remains, as do an icon of a pair of glasses to each Watch I had created, but other than that they are blank.  If I click in the Watch window, the values reappear, one at a time as I click each one.  I can cause the whole list to reappear by clicking on a plus or minus sign (tree collapse or expand), once I've revealed a watch by clicking on it.  After going through this process of making my list visible again, it all disappears again when I click f8.  Tried searching for this issue, but can't seem to find anything.  Can someone please help?

Thank you

Comment: something I found: Select the item in the Watch window, right-click and choose Edit Watch. In the Module dropdown, change that to All Modules.

Comment: Thank you, Sean, I will give that a try.  Have you seen this before?  Strange that I couldn't find this issue with a Google search...

Comment: Does this behavior persist through a system reboot? Might be obvious, but figured I'd ask.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?